# Modeling the living place of a Person

Tags: database-design, uml

I have a `dwelling` class which is a generalization of `house` and `building`. Those classes have their own properties, and the class `floor` is a composite of `building`.

[image: UML Class Diagram]

I would like to associate a `person` class. If a person lives in a building, I want to be able to retrieve the matching floor. The best solution I found is to import all properties in the parent class and make them nullable.

**Q:** Is there a more elegant way to deal with such scenario ?

**EDIT:** I forgot to say (and to draw) that `dwelling` is an abstract class, as a `:dwelling` is either a `:building` or a `:house`. As I cannot predict in which a `:person` will be, the relationship should only involve the `dwelling` class. But how instantiate once I know ?

Comment: Are you looking for advice modeling objects, or how to represent this object schema in a relational database?  Your question seems to be more directed at object modeling, and as such isn't a great fit for this site.

Comment: I'm looking for the best way to model a relationship between a class and inherited classes, so it's seems to be an object modeling problem. Sould I rather post on Stack Overflow ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

[image]

- `Person`'s home is a `LivingPlace`
- Concrete `LivingPlace`'s are `House` and `Apartment`
- Concrete `Dweling`'s are `House` and `Building`
- A `Building` has `Floor`'s, a `Floor` knows its `Building`
- A `Floor` has `Apartment`'s, a `Apartment` knows its `Floor`